# Does Three.js automatically cull objects that are not visible behind other objects?

Tags: javascript, three.js

If not, is there a way to do so?

Example

[image]

Comment: First result in google for "threejs culling" https://discourse.threejs.org/t/in-three-js-have-occlusion-culling/15076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no occlusion culling supported. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/in-three-js-have-occlusion-culling/15076. And according to that page, the only way to do it is via the WebGL API.

Comment: I don't understand why libraries don't have these by default.. it would improve performance drastically.. thank you!